# spark ml LinearRegression prediction is a constant for all observations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-regression

I'm trying to build a simple linear regression model in spark using scala. To test the method I'm trying to perform a single valriable regression using a test data set.
my data set is as follows.

x - integers from 1 to 100
y - random values generated from excel using the formula `=RANDBETWEEN(-10,10)*RAND() + x_i`

I've run a regression for this data set using python sklearn library and it gives me the best fit line (with  r<sup>2</sup> = 0.98) for the data as expected.

However, if I run a regression using spark my prediction has a constant value for all the x values in the dataset with an r<sup>2</sup> value of 2e-16.
Why doesn't this code give me the best fit line as the prediction? What am I missing?

Here's the code I'm using

### Python Code that works

```
x = np.array(df['x'])
y = np.array(df['x'])
x = x.reshape(-1,1)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)

clf = LinearRegression(normilize=True)
clf.fit(x,y)
y_predictions = clf.predict(x)
print(r2_score(y, y_predictions))
```

[Here's a plot from the python regression.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJYmI.png)

### Scala code that gives a constant prediction

```
val labelCol = "y"
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("x"))
    .setOutputCol("features")

val df2 = assembler.transform(df)

val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol(labelCol).setOutputCol("label")
val df3 = labelIndexer.fit(df2).transform(df2)

val regressor = new LinearRegression()
    .setMaxIter(10)
    .setRegParam(1.0)
    .setElasticNetParam(1.0)

val model = regressor.fit(df3)
val predictions = model.transform(df3)

val modelSummary = model.summary
println(s"r2 = ${modelSummary.r2}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was using the stringIndexer which should not be used on numeric columns. In my case, instead of using the stringIndxer, I should've just renamed the y column to label. This fixes the problem.